# Creating a Responsive Design

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design, android-xml

Hey guys I'm dealing with responsive design on Android with specifications below:

- My app should not scroll.
- I want to design it for all existing devices.

For now I opt for values/dimens file that I created for all dimension aspect in the app.

So I created w480dp, w300dp for widths and h750dp and h400dp for heights.

When I test my app in emulators:

- 320X480 Mdpi
- 480 x 854 Mdpi
- 480 x 800 Hdpi
- 768 x 1280 Xhdpi

They tooks all the w300dp X h400dp

In my testing device (galaxy S6 1440x2560) it took also w300dp X h400dp.

Anyone can tell me what qualifier should I use or even if I have a comprehension issue.

Comment: write these, like this values-w480dp-h800dp, try this and tell, have you configured it out ?

Comment: The problem is that I have to scale texviews for the S6 i made 110sp but on others it take more space than expected so it truncated.

Comment: Use dp for defining width and height and sp for textsize.

Comment: its exactly what I did but still got the problem, tx for yr comment bro

Comment: Greetings, Keep it up !